# Make ontouchListener work when two buttons are pressed

Tags: android

I have two buttons,btn1 and btn2. I want to play animation while two buttons are kept in a pressed state and the animation is stopped when either one of the button gets unpressed or even both of them get to action_up state (unPressed).

Here is my code:

```
    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.aim);

    animation.reset();
    final ImageView maxName = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btn1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getActionMasked();


            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {



                maxName.startAnimation(animation);



            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {



                maxName.clearAnimation();


            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
```

Right now i am playing it with one button, but i want to make changes according to what i wrote above. Thankyou. Waiting for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final boolean oneIsPressed = false;
        final boolean twoIsPressed = false;
        final boolean isAnimating = false;
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getActionMasked();


                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.button3) {
                        oneIsPressed = true;
                    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
                        twoIsPressed = true;
                    }

                    if (oneIsPressed && twoIsPressed && !isAnimating) {
                        isAnimating = true;
                        maxName.startAnimation(animation);
                    }
                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                    isAnimating = false;
                    maxName.clearAnimation();
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        btn1.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
        btn2.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    }
```

Comment: Working fine. But a slight little issue. Once the animation is played and buttons are untouched, now again if i try to play animation by pressing both of them, animation is not playing.

Comment: Add isAnimating = false; inside the "Action_UP". I edited the answer.

Comment: That solved the animation problem. But still theres a small glitch left in the code. The animation should only play when both buttons are pressed at an instance. It does work that way but the glitch i am talking about is , is that when one button is pressed, animation is not playing = FINE. I leave the first button and press the second button the animation starts playing = NOT FINE.

Comment: i hope i explained well, if not i can try it one more time to clearly explain. Thanks a Million

Comment: You want the animation to start only if the two buttons were presses at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Add a global boolean variable that is set to true when one button is clicked. For example:

```
private boolean isButtonOneClicked;

@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getActionMasked();


            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                 isButtonOneClicked = true;
            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                 isButtonOneClicked = false;
            }
```

Add an onTouchListener for the second button and create a global variable for this button as well, exactly the same as for the first button, it just has another name.

Create a method which checks whether both booleans are true and then starts animation

```
public void startAnimation() {
    if(isButtonOneClicked && isButtonTwoClicked) {
       maxName.startAnimation(animation);
    } else {
       maxName.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

Now call this method whenever a button is clicked or unclicked.